# How can I union Polygon in c#?

Tags: c#, union, geojson

I'm facing an issue

I have a `List<Feature>` with geojson Polygon in each feature. I want to union each Polygon, how can I do it ?

I use this function to read my filename

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Feature> features = new List<Feature>();
}
```

Comment: Use add or AddRange : features.AddRange(object);

Comment: If you actually want to get the union of two or more polygons you likely need a library, unless you want to implement the clipping code yourself. See https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ if you want recommendations. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons) for clipping algorithms.